# How to create a CSV table using python dictionary without using any modules or imports

Tags: python, csv

I have this dictionary that takes data from a csv file:

```py
def read_results(full_file_path):
    csv_dict = {}
    with open(full_file_path,'r') as t:
        table = t.readlines()[1:]
        for line in table:
            line = line.replace('\n', '')
            line = line.split(',')
            line = list(map(float, line))
            key = (line[1], line[3])
            if key in csv_dict:
                csv_dict[key].append((line[4], line[5], line[6]))
            else:
                csv_dict[key] = [(line[4], line[5], line[6])]
        return csv_dict


#that looks like this:
{(1.0, 3.0): [(602.0, 1661.0, 0.0), (945.0, 2164.0, 0.0), (141.0, 954.0, 0.0), (138.0, 913.0, 0.0),....}
```

but now i need to make use of this dictionary to create a csv of my own that needs to calculate the mean of each value row to its corresponding key couple like this:

```py
 c     b     first     finish     fix/ext 
1     3     744.67     1513.67     0.67 
0.8     3     88     858.67     0.67 
0.8     1.5     301.5     984.5     0.5 
1     1.5     419     844.5     0
```

and i cant use any outside libraries or modules, what i tried until now :

```py
def Summarize_res(results):
    with open('summary_results.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
        header = ['c','b','first','finish','fix/ext']
        f.write(str(header))
        for line in dict:
            first = sum(line[4])/len(line[4])
            finish = sum(line[5])/len(line[6])
            fix_ext = sum(line[5])/len(line[6])
```

Comment: can you elaborate a little clearly, exactly what you want to do with the dictionary to make it into a csv.

Comment: Why are you not using the `csv` module which is included with every copy of Python?

Comment: I'm doing this as part of hw for python for biologists course I'm taking and the instructor told us to do it without imports, which is why this was hard cause all the tips online are using import csv or other stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if that is what you want exactly, but here for every key it will find a mean of the corresponding values of the tuples and write it in the file. The code can definitely be simplified, but I didn't have much time for it, sorry.

```
def Summarize_res(dict):
    with open('summary_results.csv', 'w') as f:
        header = ['c','b','first','finish','fix/ext']
        f.write(','.join(str(e) for e in header))
        f.write("\n")
        for key in dict:
            key1, key2 = key
            first_arr = []
            finish_arr = []
            fix_arr = []
            for element in dict[key]:
                first, finish, fix = element
                first_arr.append(first)
                finish_arr.append(finish)
                fix_arr.append(fix)
            first_final = sum(first_arr) / len(first_arr)
            finish_final = sum(finish_arr) / len(finish_arr) 
            fix_final = sum(fix_arr) / len(fix_arr)
            result = [key1, key2, first_final, finish_final, fix_final]
            f.write(','.join(str(e) for e in result))
            f.write("\n")

Summarize_res(dict)
```

This part can be just inserted to your previous code and it should work.